# Substracting dates in PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, tkinter, pymongo

I am designing an application by using MongoDB and Tkinter. I am taking inputs from user and send them to the database. Main goal of the application is showing customers who are due for maintenance in a new window. Maintenances will be held once a year.

To do that I have a database field named mainenanceDate. This field holds next maintenance day of clients. I planned substracting maintenanceDate from currentDate and if the result smaller or equal than 0. This entity will be shown in a new window.

That is how I take inputs from user. I used dateutil because MongoDB was holding maintenanceDate as string.

```
def inputFunc():
    def addClientFunc():
        database.Clients.insert_one({
            "c_id": idEntry.get(),
            "c_name": nameEntry.get(),
            "c_firmName": firmNameEntry.get(),
            "address": addressEntry.get(),
            "engine": engineEntry.get(),
            "power": powerEntry.get(),
            "phoneNumber": phoneNumberEntry.get(),
            "email": emailEntry.get(),
            "workHour": workHourEntry.get(),
            "maintenanceDate": dateutil.parser.parse(maintenanceEntry.get())
    })
```

The problem is i'm not able to substract dates from each other because PyMongo doesn't allow me to reach maintenanceDate column. How can I reach that column? If you have any other suggestions or another way to do that please feel free to write them.

That is the code I have tried.

```
for row in database.Clients.find({},{'_id': 0}):
        delta = maintenanceDate - datetime.datetime.now()
        if(delta <= 0):
            row
            tree.insert("", END, values=[x for x in row.values()])
```

Comment: Post the code you have tried

Comment: Thank you for warning. I forgot to add the code.

Comment: Don't post code as image.  Anyway, did you try `row["maintenanceDate"]`?

Comment: Using row["maintenanceDate"] returns this error : unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'

Comment: According to the line `"maintenanceDate": dateutil.parser.parse(maintenanceEntry.get())`, `row["maintenanceDate"]` should be of type `datetime.datetime`.  If it is a string, then there is somewhere else in your code that change its content to string.